# set the "Specific Version" property of a reference in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, reference, version

I have an "ASP.NET" Website and I want to set the "specific version" property of some reference to false. But because it's a website, I dont have the references folder in my solution explorer.

How can I set the property to be false (if it's possible) in ASP.NET website?